# Powershell RegEx: How can I match lines with two matching strings?

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to pull certain pieces of data from a text log file and save that data to an output file.
The data in the text file looks like this:

```
2014-08-23 19:05:09 <nonmatching line>
2014-08-23 19:05:09 MATCH_STRING <stuff_I_don't_want> @description='12345 queue1 1 2 3' <more_stuff_I_don't_want_to_EOL>
2014-08-23 19:05:09 <nonmatching line>
2014-08-23 19:05:09 <nonmatching line>
2014-08-23 19:05:09 MATCH_STRING <stuff_I_don't_want> @description='12345 queue1 4 5 6' <more_stuff_I_don't_want_to_EOL>
```

I want to create an out put file that looks like this:

```
2014-08-23 19:05:09 12345 queue1 1 2 3
2014-08-23 19:05:09 12345 queue1 4 5 6
```

I have two RegEx expressions for the 2 necessary matches and when they are used seperately, they both work, as below:

```
(^.*?)(?=\b\tMATCH_STRING\b)
```

returns

```
2014-08-23 19:05:09
2014-08-23 19:05:09
```

and

```
(?<=@description\=')(?:(?!').)*
```

returns

```
12345 queue1 1 2 3
12345 queue1 4 5 6
```

The question is:
How do I put them together so that they match both date at the beginning of the line and the quoted string in the line?

Bonus question: Is there more efficient RegEx for what I am trying to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d+-\d+-\d+\s*\d+:\d+:\d+).*?(?=@description).*?=.(\d+)\s*(.*?[\d\s]+)
```

This regex gives all the groups you want.

See Demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lK9iD2/6

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
$matchstring = "MATCH_STRING"
$pattern = "(.*?)(?:\s*?$([regex]::Escape($matchstring)).*?description=')(.*?)'.*"

@"
2014-08-23 19:05:09 <nonmatching line>
2014-08-23 19:05:09 MATCH_STRING <stuff_I_don't_want> @description='12345 queue1 1 2 3' <more_stuff_I_don't_want_to_EOL>
2014-08-23 19:05:09 <nonmatching line>
2014-08-23 19:05:09 <nonmatching line>
2014-08-23 19:05:09MATCH_STRING <stuff_I_don't_want> @description='12345 queue1 4 5 6' <more_stuff_I_don't_want_to_EOL
"@ -split [environment]::newline |
Where-Object { $_ -match $pattern } |
ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $pattern, '$1 $2' }

2014-08-23 19:05:09 12345 queue1 1 2 3
2014-08-23 19:05:09 12345 queue1 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
^([\d-:\s]{2,}).*?(?<==)'(\d+)(.+?)'
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/oS3fU2/1)**

[image]

```
MATCH 1
1.  [39-59] `2014-08-23 19:05:09 `
2.  [107-112]   `12345`
3.  [112-125]   ` queue1 1 2 3`
MATCH 2
1.  [238-258]   `2014-08-23 19:05:09 `
2.  [306-311]   `12345`
3.  [311-324]   ` queue1 4 5 6`
```